# Google Big Query - Concatenate Year Ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I'm attempting to consolidate large datasets related to vehicle fitment, by grouping the year data. For example, a particular SKU in our database might fit a 2012 Hyundai Elantra GLS. That same SKU may also fit the same vehicle, but in the years 2013, 2014, and 2015. With very small datasets, the following query achieves what I'm looking for...:

```
SELECT
sku,
CASE
  WHEN MIN(YEAR) = MAX(YEAR) THEN MIN(YEAR)
  ELSE CONCAT(MIN(YEAR), '-', MAX(YEAR))
 END AS YEAR,
 make, model, submodel, notes
FROM
(SELECT @ldfnr:= IF((@old_make = tab.make
  AND @old_model = tab.model
  AND @old_submodel = tab.submodel
  AND @old_notes = tab.notes
  AND (@old_year = tab.`year`
  OR @old_year = tab.`year`-1)) , @ldfnr, @ldfnr+1) AS nr, tab.* ,
  @old_make := tab.make , @old_model := tab.model ,
  @old_submodel := tab.submodel , @old_notes := tab.notes ,
  @old_year := tab.`year`
FROM tableName AS tab,
  (SELECT @ldfnr:=0, @old_model:='', @old_submodel:='', @old_notes:='', @old_year:='', @old_make:=''  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY make, model, submodel, notes, `YEAR` ASC) AS mytab
GROUP BY nr
ORDER BY nr;
```

However, our datasets are quite large. For this reason, I was attempting to load the data into Google BigQuery, and perform the same query there. Perhaps it is a limitation of Google BigQuery, but it keeps returning an error related to line 9, column 2. This is where the secondary SELECT query can be found.

I have some of our sample data on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece6ee) for reference.

I'm looking at potentially using AWS to finish this up, but I thought I'd give it a try here first. I appreciate your time. :-)

Edit Below...:

Below is how the data looks right now...:

```
+------+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| SKU  | Year |   Make    | Model | Submodel |                  Notes                   |
+------+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| 0001 | 1995 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1995 | Chevrolet | Astro | CL       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1995 | Chevrolet | Astro | LS       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | CL       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | LS       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1997 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1997 | Chevrolet | Astro | LT       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 2001 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
+------+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

Below is the desired results:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| SKU  |    Year     |   Make    | Model | Submodel |                  Notes                   |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| 0001 | 1995 - 1997 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1995 - 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | CL       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1995 - 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | LS       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1997        | Chevrolet | Astro | LT       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 2001        | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

I'm sorry for not including that previously! :-)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data *and* desired results.  There is no reason to think that MySQL-specific code will run in another database, particularly code using something as bespoke as variables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the tip! I meant to include that of course, but it completely slipped my mind. Thank you so much for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to concatenate ranges of years, there are easier (and more portable) ways using window functions:

```
select sku, make, model, submodel, notes,
       (case when min(year) = max(year) then min(year)
             else min(year) || '-' || max(year)
        end) as year
from (select qt.*,
             sum(case when qtprev.make is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by qt.make, qt.model, qt.notes, qt.submodel, qt.sku order b qt.year) as grp
      from `tint-world-aces-processing.aces_table.queryTest` qt left join
           `tint-world-aces-processing.aces_table.queryTest` qtprev
           on qt.make = qtprev.make and qt.model = qtprev.model and
              qt.notes = qtprev.notes and qt.submodel = qtprev.submodel and
              qt.sku = qtprev.sku and qt.year = qtprev.year + 1
     ) qt
group by sku, make, model, submodel, notes;
```

(Note the subtle change to StandardSQL.)

Comment: This is certainly cleaner, and I really appreciate it! I attempted to run it right away, but I ended up getting an error in BigQuery. The error that I receive is...: Encountered " <ID> "max "" at line 3, column 36. Was expecting: "END".

I don't have the strongest SQL skills, and so I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: @BrianSchroeter . . . It was missing the concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and without JOINs

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 
    '0001' AS SKU, 1995 AS Year, 'Chevrolet' AS Make, 'Astro' AS Model, 'Base' AS Submodel, 
    'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;' AS Notes UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001', 1995, 'Chevrolet', 'Astro', 'CL', 'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;' UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001', 1995, 'Chevrolet', 'Astro', 'LS', 'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;' UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001', 1996, 'Chevrolet', 'Astro', 'Base', 'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;' UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001', 1996, 'Chevrolet', 'Astro', 'CL', 'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;' UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001', 1996, 'Chevrolet', 'Astro', 'LS', 'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;' UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001', 1997, 'Chevrolet', 'Astro', 'Base', 'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;' UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001', 1997, 'Chevrolet', 'Astro', 'LT', 'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;' UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001', 2001, 'Chevrolet', 'Astro', 'Base', 'Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.;'
)
SELECT SKU,
  IF(MIN(Year) = MAX(Year), 
    CAST(MIN(Year) AS STRING), 
    CONCAT(CAST(MIN(Year) AS STRING), ' - ', CAST(MAX(Year) AS STRING))
  ) AS Year, 
  Make, Model, Submodel, Notes
FROM (
  SELECT SKU, Year, Make, Model, Submodel, Notes, 
    SUM(Step) OVER(PARTITION BY SKU, Make, Model, Submodel, Notes ORDER BY Year) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT SKU, Year, Make, Model, Submodel, Notes, 
      IFNULL(SIGN(Year - 1 - LAG(Year) OVER(PARTITION BY SKU, Make, Model, Submodel, Notes ORDER BY Year)), 1) AS Step
    FROM yourTable  
  )
)
GROUP BY SKU, Make, Model, Submodel, Notes, grp
```